# Find the term p with matrix .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

how I can solve this. Find $p$. Let $x,y,z,p\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $a,b,c$ are constants, such that 
$$2\langle p,x-y\rangle=(\vert\vert x\vert\vert^2-\vert\vert y\vert\vert^2)-(a^2-b^2)$$
$$2\langle p,z-y\rangle=(\vert\vert z\vert\vert^2-\vert\vert y\vert\vert^2)-(c^2-b^2)$$
$$2\langle p,x-z\rangle=(\vert\vert x\vert\vert^2-\vert\vert z\vert\vert^2)-(a^2-c^2)$$

I think the left ride side, if $k=(k_1,...,k_n)$, then I can write the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x_1-y_1 & x_2-y_2 & ... & x_n-y_n\\
z_1-y_1 & z_2-y_2 & ... & z_n-y_n\\
x_1-z_1 & x_2-z_2 & ... & x_n-z_n\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
p_1\\
p_2\\
\vdots\\
p_n\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
And the right side is the same. But, what happen if exist terms emptys, maybe the matrix can't be resolve. Any hint?? , I think maybe works the singular value descomposition (SVD).. but I not sure. Regards

Comment: Just to clarify: are you using the bracket notation as some sort of Inner Product? It doesn't appear to be one...

Comment: @Xoque55 Yes, it is